# Validación fallida datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap, validación, datepicker

Presento un problema estoy realizando una validación con formValidation en la cual valido una fecha, si escribo la fecha me acepta la validación pero si escojo la fecha desde el datepicker me la deja siempre como invalida. Me pueden ayudar? Muchas gracias.

Campo formulario:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="fechaNacimiento">Fecha de Nacimiento:</label>  
       <div class="col-md-6">
          <input type="text" id="fechaNacimiento" name="fechaNacimiento"  placeholder="dd/mm/aaaa" class="form-control input-md"  tabindex="11"></input>
       </div>
</div>
```

Script datepicker:

```
   $(function () {
   $.datepicker.regional['es'] =
  {
     closeText: 'Cerrar',
     prevText: 'Previo',
     nextText: 'Próximo',
     monthNames: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio',    'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
     monthNamesShort: ['Ene', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dic'],
     monthStatus: 'Ver otro mes', yearStatus: 'Ver otro año',
     dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sábado'],
     dayNamesShort: ['Dom', 'Lun', 'Mar', 'Mie', 'Jue', 'Vie', 'Sáb'],
     dayNamesMin: ['Do', 'Lu', 'Ma', 'Mi', 'Ju', 'Vi', 'Sa'],
     dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', firstDay: 0,
     altField: "#alt_date",
     altFormat: "yy/mm/dd",
     initStatus: 'Selecciona la fecha', isRTL: false};
     $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['es']);
     $("#fechaNacimiento").datepicker({showAnim: 'slideDown', changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, yearRange: '-70:+0'});
    });
```

Validación:

```
$().ready(function() {

FormValidation.Validator.mayorEdad = {
    validate: function(validator, $field, options) {
        var value = $field.val();
        var fechanacimiento = moment(value, "DD-MM-YYYY");

        if(!fechanacimiento.isValid())
            return false;

        var years = moment().diff(fechanacimiento, 'years');

        return years >= 18;
    }
}


 $('#formularioRegistro').formValidation({// Validación datos capa cliente. TENER PRESENTE EL ID DEL FORM
    err: {container: 'tooltip'}, //muestra en tooltips
    icon: {valid: 'fa fa-thumbs-up', invalid: 'fa fa-thumbs-down', validating: 'fa fa-refresh'}, //iconos
    //locale: 'es_ES', //idioma - debe enlazar el archivo "es_ES.js"
    fields: {

        fechaNacimiento: {
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'La fecha de nacimiento es requerida'
                },
                mayorEdad: {
                    message: 'No es mayor de edad'
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

});

Cabe aclarar que tengo todas las librerias correctas del datepicker y form validation.

Answer (score 1):

El formato de fecha que le estás dando a jQuery UI Datepicker es distinto al que le estás pasando al validador:

Datepicker: `dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'`

FormValidation: `var fechanacimiento = moment(value, "DD-MM-YYYY");`

Usa el mismo formato en ambas, por ejemplo:

Datepicker: `dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'`

FormValidation: `var fechanacimiento = moment(value, "YYYY-MM-DD");`

Comment: el formato en el cual esta en el datepicker es 'dd/mm/yy' y en el formValidation es 'DD-MM-YYYY'. La parte que ves que esta en altFormat: "yy/mm/dd", es para que me mande a la base de datos en ese formato.

Comment: Aún así están distintos, no? me refiero a que uno utiliza slashes (/) y el otro guiones (-) por ende no debería pasar la validación.